# What’s the difference between ‘from the sofa’ and ‘on the sofa’?

Tags: sentence-meaning, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between

1. I turned on the TV from the sofa

and

2. I turned on the TV on the sofa

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of meaning, there isn't much.

This is because they both mean you were sitting on the sofa and used the remote control to send a signal from the sofa to the tv to turn on.

In general "on" and "from" have quite different meanings.

Comment: I think "turned on the TV on the sofa" could mean that that TV was located on the sofa.

Comment: @Jack O’Flaherty No, James K answered my question right.

Comment: @user2848 No, Jack O'Flaherty is right: the sentence is grammatically ambiguous, although there is only one interpretation that would normally make sense.  Consider "I looked at the cat on the chair" - that would normally be interpreted to mean that the cat was on the chair, not that I was on the chair.

Comment: It could mean that that TV was located on the sofa,  but it probably *doesn't*.  Do you have a TV that you keep on the sofa? This is almost a textbook illustration of a situation in which a sematic ambiguity is removed by context.